# Rate Change of Radius of Reducing Sphere

Tags: calculus, volume, spheres

Suppose the volume of a sphere is given by $V$ and is declining by $Q$ per second where $Q$ is a constant volume significantly smaller than the sphere.

What function would give us instantaneous velocity at a given radius($v(r)$) where $v$ is velocity?

Work so far:

Initial radius is:
$r_0=\sqrt[3]{(V/(4\pi/3))}$

radius after 1 second is:
$r_1=\sqrt[3]{(r^34\pi/3 - Q)/(4\pi/3)}$

And then difference in radius is:
$r_\Delta =\sqrt[3]{(V/(4\pi/3))}-\sqrt[3]{(r^34\pi/3 - Q)/(4\pi/3)}$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: The instantaneous velocity of the volume declining? $V$$(r)$.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to MSE! Just a few things: (1) You need to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and (2) if you post a homework-like problem, please make sure to explain what you have tried, and please try to ask about the concepts in general as opposed to a super-specific example of them, that way we can help you—and others—to the best of our abilities. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to wonderful site!

Comment: Thank you for your question, kimi. For example, if i take the difference in radius(rΔ) and divide by 1 second then would get a velocity toward the center of the sphere. But as that velocity is always changing, I'm uncertain how to derive the instantaneous velocity in this case. Little "v" was meant to represent velocity while big "V"= the volume.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be viewed as a calculus problem: Assume Q is expressed as a positive number.

$$
V=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}\\
\frac{dV}{dt}=-Q=\frac{4\pi}{3}\frac{d(r^3)}{dt}\\
\frac{d(r^3)}{dt}=-\frac{3Q}{4\pi}\\
r^3=r_0^3-\frac{3Q}{4\pi}t\\
r=\sqrt[3]{r_0^3-\frac{3Q}{4\pi}t}\\
v=\frac{dr}{dt}
$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, Cye, for that help. I'm not clear on how to get the derivative of $dr/dt$ in this case. I'm self-studying Calculus but have not come across a situation with multiple variables needing to be differentiated(Q,t,r). Oddly enough, I get a very good approximation with $v=(Q/4pi)/r^2$, but I'm not sure if that is the correct derivative or how to even come to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

After much thought, I've come to a very straightforward solution to this:

Given that

$V=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$

and

$A=4\pi r^2$

Therefore

$Q=dV/dt = (4\pi r^2)(dr/dt)$

Solve for $dr/dt$

$dr/dt=\frac {dV/dt}{4\pi r^2}$

Since $v = dr/dt$ and $Q=dV/dt$ then

$v=\frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}$